# IS NULL vs = NULL.... How to avoid a huge IF ELSE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A scaled down look at my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM
    Settings s
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationUserSettings ous ON s.SettingID = ous.SettingID 
        AND (ProfileID = @ProfileID OR ProfileID IS NULL)
```

Now, in the `OrganizationUserSettings` table I have two row that look like this:

```
ID    SettingID    ProfileID 
----------------------------
1        3           NULL
2        3           50
```

So as would be expected, in my results I am getting both rows.  But I need to be getting only one row.  If there is a match for `ProfileID = @ProfileID`, then I need that one.  If there isn't, then I'll take the one that's NULL.

Or, better yet... in short, here's my real problem.  I could do a giant IF ELSE like this:

```
IF (@ProfileSys IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM
        Settings s
        LEFT JOIN OrganizationUserSettings ous ON s.SettingID = ous.SettingID 
            AND (ProfileID IS NULL)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        SELECT 
        ...
    FROM
        Settings s
        LEFT JOIN OrganizationUserSettings ous ON s.SettingID = ous.SettingID 
            AND (ProfileID = @ProfileID)
END
```

But I REALLY don't want to have to do that. What I'm showing you here is just part of a much larger query (I've scaled it down here for simplicity sake.) And I don't want to have to make a fully dynamic query.

Is there a way to do this in one line of the original JOIN?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you only looking for a single row to be returned in all cases? Cos if so you can select top 1, and order by non null ProfileId.

Comment: Good question. No, there will be many rows returned from the overall query.  But per join, (or per SettingID) there will only be one row. In other words, in the OrganizationUserSetting table, the SettingID will be unique.

Comment: What about a coalesce? `ProfileID = coalesce(@ProfileID,NULL)`

Comment: Bah - scratch what I just said. In the OrganizationUserSetting , the SettingID will NOT be unique. But the JOIN in question will only return one row per SettingID.  Either with ProfileID being NULL, or having a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, there's a simple solution:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM
Settings s
LEFT JOIN OrganizationUserSettings ous ON s.SettingID = ous.SettingID 
    AND (ProfileID = @ProfileID OR (ProfileID IS NULL AND @ProfileID IS NULL))
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this works in all cases, the question suggests there will be instances where @ProfileID is not `NULL` but there will not be a match in `OrganizationUserSettings`.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller -- reading your comment carefully... I may have misworded my OP.  There should not be a case where ProfileID has a value but there is no matching value in the OrganizationUserSettings table, ProfileID column.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller It's a `LEFT JOIN` so it would return a `NULL` in that case anyway

Comment: @AaronDietz Yes, but presumably the other columns have value, there's a big difference between `1, 3, NULL` and `NULL, NULL, NULL`. Though based on OP's clarification it looks like the entire scenario isn't a concern.